# SQl join with count group by

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two tables

one is

> Receivesms(Matchdate,Matchtime,Keyword,SmsMessage,Mobileno)

another is

> QAoptios(Keyword,Question,Answeroption,Matchdate,Matchtime)

I need to find the count of `SmsMessage` which have the value same as `Answeroption` on same `Matchdate`,`Matchtime` and same `Keyword`. and also i need to filter on Receivesms.Matchdate='2012-12-25 00:00:00.000'

Comment: For this, I think it might be best if you looked at a googled example of joining two tables with a GROUP BY.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  q.AnswerOption,
  COUNT(SmsMessage) TheCount
FROM Receivesms r
INNER JOIN QAoptions q  ON r.Matchdate = q.Matchdate
                       AND r.Matchtime = q.Matchtime
                       AND r.Keyword = q.keyword
GROUP BY q.AnswerOption;
```

Comment: Doesn't check to see if `AnswerOption` = `SmsMessage`

Comment: @DWright - Are you looking for only the COUNT not with a `GROUP BY`, if so add this predicate to the `JOIN` and remove the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

**try this one**

```
SELECT count(*) from Receivesms as a  inner join QAoptios as b on a.keyword=b.keyword
and a.matchtime=b.matchtime and a.matchdate=b.matchdate and a.value=b.answeroption
```

Answer (score 0):

use can use:

```
    select count(*) from Recievesms r,QAoptios q 
    where
    r.Matchdate = q.Matchdate 
    and
    r.Matchtime = q.Matchtime
    and
    r. Keyword =q.Keyword
    and
    r.SmsMessage = q.Answeroption;
```

or

```
    select count(*) from from Recievesms as r
    inner join
    QAoptios as q 
    on  
    r.SmsMessage =   q.Answeroption;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(R.SmsMessage)
FROM Receivesms R
INNER JOIN QAoptios Q ON 
R.Keyword=Q.Keyword AND
R.Matchdate=Q.Matchdate AND
R.Matchtime=Q.Matchtime AND
R.SmsMessage=Q.AnswerOption
```

Or you can add GROUP BY clause if you want to show AnswerQuestion, like this:

```
SELECT Q.AnswerOption, COUNT(R.SmsMessage) as TheCount
FROM Receivesms R
INNER JOIN QAoptios Q ON 
R.Keyword=Q.Keyword AND
R.Matchdate=Q.Matchdate AND
R.Matchtime=Q.Matchtime AND
R.SmsMessage=Q.AnswerOption
GROUP BY Q.AnswerOption
```